# Biblatex-apa style is missing a comma in the text-citations. why?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6

i have a follow up question to a previously answered one regarding commas in citations and references: 
 
 [Biblatex-apa style is missing a comma in the references. why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97712/biblatex-apa-style-is-missing-a-comma-in-the-references-why/129390#129390) 
 
it works for me in the reference section, but as a text-citation, there is still a comma missing. according to APA 6th, there should be also a comma in front of the "&" when 3 or more authors are used. 
 
like this:

> (Tom, Jerry, & Donald, 2012).

right now it looks like this:

> (Tom, Jerry & Donald, 2012).

How can i fix it?

Comment: Which version are you using? It seems fine in the latest version (6.1).

Comment: I don't think this is a follow-up question; you should comment on some of the answers or edit the original question to include the additional information.